# 3D Hexagonal Maps

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xna, basic

So im trying to develop a game in the XNA 4.0 framework in Visual Studio 2010, and I wanted to create a game that would have some sort of 3D hexagonal map. I've been researching, and i saw this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgdraYpT9vU

This guy claims to have made this with just XNA 4.0 in Visual Studio, which is quite stunning(for me). So here is my question. You don't have to explain how to do it in here, as it would probably be WAYYY too long, but does anybody know a guide somewhere which I can reference in order to learn how to make this?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've tried to make question more specific it's still too broad (or too specific, from another angle).

I doubt there is specific guide how to make similar game using same tools. But it's easy to find information about individual aspects: game architecture, 3D [in XNA], hexagonal maps. For that matter there is very good resourse called [Amit’s Game Programming Information](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html). I think it have all information necessary for a start on *any* game.

Comment: Alright, sorry for not making it specific enough, and thank you very much for the resource. Much appreciated!